# Align two georreferenced rasters which have different resolution in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, alignment

I have two rasters in .TIFF format which have different resolution, different information and extent but georreferenced in the same coordinate system .

I would like to know if it possible to align the pixels of this two rasters to have them in the same position.

I was try with the Align raster tool in QGIS but it doesn´t works well.

Comment: Add a) pixel size and b) origo of both images.

Comment: You said that the rasters are georeferenced but they have different resolution and extent and you want to align the pixels. What is the purpose of aligning the pixels and what is the expected result since you mentioned that the rasters are georeferenced?